# Views slideshow displaying multiple items

Tags: views

Under view action advanced Options of 'Views slideshow' I have defined 4 items per slide which is displaying 4 items one under each other. Is there a way we can display them in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add views slidehshow cycle module as well

Comment: already using that, in-fact my slide show is working but the images are displaying vertically, I want them to display horizontally

Comment: please add the error or warning you get on inspect element

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following bit of CSS to get multiple items displayed in a single row:

```
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row-item {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 13px;
}
```